# Map image with zoom in and zoom out as well as marker on different position of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, maps

I am having trouble in developing mobile-web application. I want to allow users to upload map as an image of any location and other will tag or add marker on different position of it. I want want this functionality with zoom in and zoom out. I am able to do this without zoom in and zoom out. Can any body help me to achieve this by adding zoom in and zoom out on image with tags.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/wiki. it is jquery component that you can use and has examples of zooming -in and -out with the coordinates and markers.

Comment: Thanks Alexi. But my in my requirement I also want to tag a particular location. e.g. if I have uploaded a map(as image) of a school then I  want to tag different location such as library,play ground ect. and when we will zoom in zoom out then these tags are also required to move with that particular location as happend in google map.